# First time to add text to textField [Swift]

Tags: swift, textfield

I think it is something really easy but I am a noob and I can't figure out what to do, So I am trying to check if the TextField has nothing inside it, it would let the user write something in it, but if it has some text saved (I have saved the data using NSUserDefaults) in there when you quit the app it will remain the text that was typed in that TextField. 
I had accomplished this before but something went wrong and stopped working.

Here is what I have done:

```
var notTheFirstTime = false

     if notTheFirstTime == true{
        let mail = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("usersMailID") as! String
        textField.text = "\(mail)"
    }
```

Here is the part where the text filed is saved and change the status of the "notTheFirstTime" to true

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    performAction()
    return true
}

func performAction() {
    notTheFirstTime = false
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(textField.text!, forKey: "usersMailID")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    print("Saved!!!!!!")
    saveLabel.text! = "Saved!"
    savedIcon.image = UIImage(named: "Saved")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two things in this code, After the text saved in to user default you should use

```
 notTheFirstTime = true
```

but you set this as false in performAction()

Second one is you should use notTheFirstTime value also as a User defaults. When you close the app. This value also rest to the false( as you given on initial step of the application) So use it's value also as a user defaults.